# Safari issue with vertical centering

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, justify

I am designing my personal website and some codes doesn't work in safari.
it's my website url
http://hoomansanjabi.ir

I want to centre my logo.
I'm thinking safari has problem with this codes:

```
.header {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/ to provide example of your problem

Comment: Which version of safari and are you using all the necessary vendor prefixes and old syntaxes?